# How to print all elements in list after apending?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my Vending Machine program is not printing all the elements in the list, after appending them all. For example:

- The cost is 50p.
- The amount inserted is 62p
- It should return: ['10p'], ['2p']
- but it only returns: ['10p']

Any help is appreciated, and I appreciate any help to improve my code as well, I am very new to programming!

```
prompt_cost = int(input("What are the total cost in pence? "))
prompt_insert_money = int(input("Insert the amount of pence (max 100p) into the machine: "))
coins = ["50p", "20p", "10p", "5p", "2p", "1p", "0p"]
list = []

for coin in coins:
    pence_change = prompt_insert_money - prompt_cost
    if pence_change < 0:
        missing_amount = prompt_cost - prompt_insert_money
        print("Sorry, you do not have the sufficient amount inserted in!", "You are missing", int(missing_amount), "pence!")
        list.append(coins[6])
        break
    if pence_change == 0:
        list.append(coins[6])
        break
    if pence_change >= 50:
        list.append(coins[0])
        pence_change - 50
        break
    elif pence_change >= 20:
        list.append(coins[1])
        pence_change - 20
        break
    elif pence_change >= 10:
        list.append(coins[2])
        pence_change - 10
        break
    elif pence_change >= 5:
        list.append(coins[3])
        pence_change - 5
        break
    elif pence_change >= 2:
        list.append(coins[4])
        pence_change - 2
        break
    elif pence_change >= 1:
        list.append(coins[5])
        pence_change - 1
        break
print("You have received the following coins:", list)
```

Comment: That's because the loop breaks as soon as it calculates the first pence amount, while you are calculating the remaining pence, you are not calling the function again with the new pence amount. You might want to try a recursive approach for this problem.

Comment: Do not call your variables `list`, as `list` is list constructor.

Comment: In addition to the two suggestions above, you also need to change how `pence_change` is first initialised and then altered. Right now, every time the loop executes, it sets the value of `pence_change` to the two external variables, so you'll get the same result each time. Solution: put `pence_change = prompt_insert_money - prompt_cost` before the start of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prompt_cost = int(input("What are the total cost in pence? "))
prompt_insert_money = int(input("Insert the amount of pence (max 100p) into the machine: "))
coins = ["50p", "20p", "10p", "5p", "2p", "1p", "0p"]
lst = []

pence_change = prompt_insert_money - prompt_cost
for coin in coins:
    if pence_change < 0:
        missing_amount = prompt_cost - prompt_insert_money
        print("Sorry, you do not have the sufficient amount inserted in!", "You are missing", int(missing_amount), "pence!")
        lst.append(coins[6])
        break

    if pence_change == 0:
        break

    if pence_change >= 50:
        lst.append(coins[0])
        pence_change-= 50

    elif pence_change >= 20:
        lst.append(coins[1])
        pence_change-= 20

    elif pence_change >= 10:
        lst.append(coins[2])
        pence_change-= 10

    elif pence_change >= 5:
        lst.append(coins[3])
        pence_change-= 5

    elif pence_change >= 2:
        lst.append(coins[4])
        pence_change-=2

    elif pence_change >= 1:
        lst.append(coins[5])
        pence_change-= 1

print("You have received the following coins:", lst)
```

I have modified your code as you expected ,

Comment: Hi, thank you Ananth.P. This solution worked perfectly. I've got a question, how do I best going about to getting better and understanding more of Python? When I am practicing questions like this, I am usually stuck for days with no progress.

Comment: @wonjo keep practicing, whenever you get stuck , first go with a simpler solution and     move forward step by step..Keep in mind, Fundamentals are very important.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is getting only the first coin you require. What you have to do at the most basic level is keep iterating over the coins till the `pence_change` is 0.

```
prompt_cost = int(input("What are the total cost in pence? "))
prompt_insert_money = int(input("Insert the amount of pence (max 100p) into the machine: "))
coins = ["50p", "20p", "10p", "5p", "2p", "1p", "0p"]
lst = []

pence_change = prompt_insert_money - prompt_cost
if pence_change < 0:
    missing_amount = prompt_cost - prompt_insert_money
    print("Sorry, you do not have the sufficient amount inserted in!", "You are missing", int(missing_amount), "pence!")
    lst.append(coins[6])

while pence_change >= 0:
    if pence_change == 0:
        lst.append(coins[6])
        break
    if pence_change >= 50:
        lst.append(coins[0])
        pence_change -= 50
    elif pence_change >= 20:
        lst.append(coins[1])
        pence_change -= 20
    elif pence_change >= 10:
        lst.append(coins[2])
        pence_change -= 10
    elif pence_change >= 5:
        lst.append(coins[3])
        pence_change -= 5
    elif pence_change >= 2:
        lst.append(coins[4])
        pence_change -= 2
    elif pence_change >= 1:
        lst.append(coins[5])
        pence_change -= 1
print("You have received the following coins:", lst)
```

Comment: Hi Prakhar Londhe, thank you for this solution, however, there was a problem with this solution. It showed you have received '[0p]' every time. I've got a question for you, how do you best go about to getting better at Python? I am currently practicing questions like this but I get stuck quite often and end up Googling for hours.

Comment: only [0p] every time or 0p with other coins also.. If it is with other coins also, then I put it deliberately there, I thought You wanted the last coin to be 0p. As for getting better at python, I would suggest first to learn python in an organized manner ( any course would be good ). And then try solving competitive programming problems from sites like codechef or hackerearth.

Comment: 0p with the other coins, sorry about the confusion there. Also thank you for the advice and for taking your time to help me with my problem. I really appreciate it.